# UIButtonのaddTargetがうまくいかない

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

環境:Mac/High Sierra 10.13.6/swift4.2/xcode 10.0

下記コードでUIButtonをaddSubviewした時に、うまく動きません。
ViewController上でUIButtonを直接定義するとうまく動くことが確認できました。
また、BulbSwitchButtonクラス内のイニシャライザでViewControllerを引数で指定して、プロパティに追加(weak var vc:ViewController)すればうまくいくことも確認しました。
ただ、下記コードのようにViewController上で、他クラスのUIButtonプロパティをaddSubview()した時に、クリックしてもBulbSwitchButtonクラスのaction()が動作しない理由がわかりませんでした。

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        var bulb = Bulb(id: 1, state: true)
        var bulbSwitch = BulbSwitchButton(bulb: bulb)
        bulbSwitch.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/7, height: self.view.bounds.height/7)
        bulbSwitch.button.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(bulbSwitch.button)

        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }

    @objc func testAction(_ sender:UIButton){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }


}
```

Bulb.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Bulb{
    let id:Int
    var state:Bool = false
    var image:UIImage?
    var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var onFilename:String = "on"
    var offFilename:String = "off"

    init(id:Int){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        self.id=id
        self.setImage()
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }

    init(id:Int,state:Bool){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        self.state=state
        self.id=id
        self.setImage()
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }

    func setImage(){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        if self.state{
            self.image = UIImage(named: self.onFilename)
            self.imageView.image = self.image
        }else{
            self.image = UIImage(named: self.offFilename)
            self.imageView.image = self.image
        }
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }


    func on(){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        self.state = true
        setImage()
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }

    func off(){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        self.state = false
        setImage()
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }

    func setOnOff(state:Bool){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        if state{
            self.on()
        }else{
            self.off()
        }
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }
}


class BulbSwitchButton{
    let bulb:Bulb
    let id:Int
    var filename:String = "back"
    let button:UIButton = UIButton()

    init(bulb:Bulb){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        self.bulb = bulb
        self.id = self.bulb.id
        self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.button.setImage(UIImage(named: filename), for: .normal)
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }

    @objc func action(_ sender:UIButton){
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
        Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いったいどのようなコードの場合に期待の動作をすることを確かめられたのか、記載の内容だけではよくわからないのですが、掲載されたコードが動かない原因ははっきりしているので、今回は特に問題はないでしょう。

根本的な原因は、`BulbSwitchButton`のインスタンスを保持している変数`bulbSwitch`がメソッド`viewDidLoad()`のローカル変数であるためです。作成された`BulbSwitchButton`のインスタンスは`bulbSwitch`にしか強参照を保持されていないので、`viewDidLoad()`の終了とともに解放されてしまいます。

`BulbSwitchButton`のイニシャライザの中で`self`(== `viewDidLoad()`の`bulbSwitch`)を`addTarget`していますが、UIControlはtargetの弱参照しか保持せず、targetがどこかで解放されてしまうと黙ってactionを無視してしまいます。

---

と言うわけで手っ取り早く対応するには、`bulbSwitch`をインスタンス変数にして、`viewDidLoad()`が終了しても、`BulbSwitchButton`のインスタンスが解放されないようにしてしまえば良いでしょう。

```
var bulbSwitch: BulbSwitchButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    Logger.debug(Logger.Message.START_FUNCTION.rawValue)
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bulb = Bulb(id: 1, state: true)
    bulbSwitch = BulbSwitchButton(bulb: bulb)
    bulbSwitch.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/7, height: self.view.bounds.height/7)
    bulbSwitch.button.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(bulbSwitch.button)

    Logger.debug(Logger.Message.END_FUNCTION.rawValue)
}
```

ただ、少し使い方を誤るとtargetに設定したはずのインスタンスが解放されてしまうと言うのは、現在のクラス分割があまりうまく出来ていないせいだと思った方が良いでしょう。(他にも直したいところはあれこれありますが、まだ発展途上のコードのようですし、今回は置いておきます。)

Comment: ありがとうございます！理解できました。クラス分割やその他のコーディングの技術についてどのように学ぶことができますでしょうか。おおよそのネット上の例だとサンプルなので大概UIViewController上に書かれているのですが、ファイルの行数がすぐに膨れ上がってしまうため、現在はViewController単位に必要なViewを作成してレイアウトを作るクラスを別ファイルにまとめています。そのため、このような結果となってしまったと考えています。クラス分割やファイル分割の指針のようなものがあればご教示いただけますと大変助かります。

Comment: @shin-ichi さん、残念ながら「クラス分割やファイル分割の指針のようなもの」は私自身模索中で、こうすれば、と言うのをお見せできるようなまとまった何かは持ち合わせていません。ただ、評価の基準と言うものはあって、回答中に示したように「クラスを使う側がその使い方に細心の注意を払わないとうまく動かない」とか「やろうとしていることに比べて、書かなきゃいけないコードが複雑になりすぎる」なんてものは不合格と考えるようにしています。私なら`BulbSwitchButton`のようなクラスは`UIView`か`UIControl`(あるいは`UIButton`)のサブクラスにするでしょうか。それはそれで面倒な点も出てくるのですが、ある意味「自然な面倒さ」であって、一度うまく動くと「`UIButton`と同じように扱える」ように作れますから。最初に書いたようにいつも試行錯誤ですが、自分標語は Make it simple. コードが必要以上に複雑になりすぎていると感じたら立ち止まって考え直すようにしています。